# Problems converting between serialization output and BigInteger

Tags: java, serialization, arrays, rsa, biginteger

I'm in the middle of a school project, where I have to demonstrate RSA.

I'm serializing objects using the fairly basic ObjectOutputStream and returning it as a byte array.

The RSA method I'm using is very similar to the one [found here.](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/rsa/implementation.html)

The problem arises in the conversion between the byte array from the serialization and the BigIntegers in the RSA encryption.

Looking at the bytes reveals the fact that there are several negative values in the byte array, explaining the problematic conversion.

How do I work around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question and tangens' answer, I couldnt perform the encryption on the regular serialized object. However using the [XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) class I could create an XML-serialization without odd non ascii-convertible numbers.

The next problem was that I couldn't encrypt anything longer than the [modulo part (or *n*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#A_working_example) of the RSA crypto-system without breaking the clear text up into fitting parts.

I hope this will eventually help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray() instead of serializing the BigInteger. Serialization will give you a format only suitable for deserialization, but not for further calculations.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Sorry I weren't making myself completely clear, but I'm not serializing the BigInteger. Given the last part of your answer though, what i'm trying to do doesnt make sense. You gave me an idea i'll try working in tomorrow - thanks again! :D